# C# => Arduino connection crash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

So I have an Arduino connected to my computer in serial. And unity send data to the arduino. It works for some seconds and then the connection stop working and I have to beboot everything. 
Here is the error :

> Un périphérique attaché au système ne fonctionne pas correctement.
>
> at System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream.ReportIOError (System.String
>   optional_arg) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write (System.String str) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.WriteLine
>   (System.String str) [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.SerialPort:WriteLine
>   (string)   at FlyController.sendCommand (System.String cmd) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at FlyController.Update () [0x00000] in
>   :0

Here is the code of the connection (for the moment the C# just send data but doesn't read anything)

```
port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);//\\\\.\\COM10
port.ReadTimeout = 50;//Peut etre le passer a 500
port.Open();
```

Any idea?

Comment: could you please provide the code that write/read  to/from the port?

Comment: I use serialcommand.h library

Comment: I meant the relevant code in the C# side (not the arduino side).

Comment: I also recommend to do your 'read()' in a separate thread because 'read()' is a blocking method meaning that Unity should wait for it till it reads data. Also make sure you do 'port.Close()' at the end.

Comment: I don't read in unity. And the code is just port.write("###");

Comment: Have you set the writing timeout? port.WriteTimeout = 500;

Comment: Also make sure your string in the port.Write() is never null.

Comment: Is your port variable a local variable or a member variable? Make sure it is a member variable and does not go out of scope.

Comment: I'd use the IsOpen() method before the write to make sure it is open. If not, open it. In this case, the question is why the port gets closed again and again after some period.

Comment: Yes there's a timeout and I'm sure for the variable and the string is never null. Do you think the best is to make a port.close at the end of the application or at the end of each command? (There is command each seconds)

Comment: And the connection is always open

Comment: Put port.Close() when you are done with the port.

Comment: The problem remain :/

Comment: what unity version are you using?

Comment: 2017.0.1f3 so don't think any problem

Comment: I don't think your unity version is the problem however the most reliable version is the LTS versions which currently is Unity 2017.4.x